# Karatsuba Multiplication Rule in dividing a Number in two parts

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, multiplication

In Karatsuba algorithm for multiplying two numbers, we divide each number into two. For example:

```
x= 1234
y= 2456
```

Then a = 12, b = 34, c = 24 , d = 56

What if the digits in each number are not even, or the same? What is the rule in dividing it into two parts?

Example:

```
 x = 12345
 y = 2478
```

or

```
 x = 12456778
 y = 241
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The most common approach is to take the longest number, and divide it in half (rounding an odd number of digits arbitrarily). So for

```
x = 12345
y = 2478
```

you would get `a=12`, `b=345`, `c=2`, `d=478`. Since the number of digits in `x` is not even, we are free to choose whether to split into `a=12` and `b=345` or `a=123` and `b=45`; it makes no difference to the running time. For your second example

```
x = 12456778
y = 241
```

you would get `a=1245`, `b=6778`, `c=0`, `d=241`.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case we should pad with zeros up to an even degree of the largest of the two numbers. 
Suppose that $x \ge y$ and $2^n \le x < 2^{n+1}$. Then one should represent $x, y$ as 
$$x = x_1\cdot 2^{\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil} + x_2, y = y_1\cdot 2^{\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil} + y_2$$
and then apply Karatsuba Rule. The total complexity is still $O(n^{\log_23})$